# Looping for with cat and data with spaces

Tags: bash, unix, for-loop, cat, sunos

I have a data file with some white spaces:

file.txt

```
102436350   000007660809        000007660809        000CLPCCNMN10
```

I tried this:

```
grep ${acc} ${fxc} > registro
IFS=' '
for reg in `cat registro` line
do
    echo ${reg}
done
```

But the result gives me the first string of text before space:

```
102436350
```

This file is a big one but in each line I have many white spaces.

Comment: Don't use `cat`, don't use a `for` loop; see [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Comment: Also: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: @CharlesDuffy (@chepner): Is there a canonical SO Q&A for this?  Should we find one?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The dup here is listed on the `bash` tag info page, but that page is getting a bit difficult to use.

Comment: Thanks a lot all of you for this help.

Comment: @chepner: Thanks for the pointer — I guess that shows how often I look at the Bash tag wiki.  Yes, it is a bit large and verging on unwieldy.  The information is there, if only you can find it.